# Can I download a query as a csv?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, download, google-cloud-sql

I try download a Left Join Query with 110 columns and 60.000 rows in a CSV. I am using GAE with python and i need that the download occurs when user click in one button of my portal, but make this is imposible because always appear the DeadLineError when I execute my code.

I try use:

```
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=10, callback=None)
    urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(10)
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "url",method="POST")
```

But this don't function.

Please, can somebody  give me a mind? It's obligatory than i use GAE with python. If it's necesary more information i can give it.

Comment: I'd be curious if you can pull large numbers of objects like that out of GAE in one query without hitting some kind of limit. 60000 rows x 110 cols is about 7 million data elements, and if each one were 10 bytes, thats at least 70MB.

Comment: [GAE Quotas Page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Safety_Quotas_and_Billable_Quotas) says you get like 56MB/minute on free.  Not a problem on paid.  I think once upon a time there was also a limit of 30 secs per request which is plenty of time to download on broadband, I suppose.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is any way to do this for free, or at least, make sure it can be done by payment and payment explain by which to guarantee this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome the `DeadlineError`, On button click create a `task queue` for generating CSV file and save it in `Blobstore`. Once the file generated, Display `Blobserve URL` using `Channel API` in your page. When user click the Download URL serve the blob.

More Info:

[Serving a Blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Serving_a_blob) , [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/)